# Create Custom Buttons in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, pysimplegui

I'm making a GUI with PySimpleGui and I want one of my buttons to be a circle and one to be bigger. Is there a way to do this? If so, how? I'm using the TKinter port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try option `image_filename` or `image_data` of `sg.Button`, and set correct button color from theme setting, also set border width to 0.

Here's example how it work, remember to use your image file in following code.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ('Helvetica', 12, 'bold italic')
sg.theme('Dark')
sg.set_options(font=font)
colors = (sg.theme_background_color(), sg.theme_background_color())

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Blue\nCircle', button_color=colors, image_filename='d:/circle_blue.png', border_width=0)]
]
window = sg.Window('Image Button', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot the sg. Still I'm getting the error "AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'image_filename'"

Comment: No `sg` forgot here, you may misunderstand something here. Don't use `sg.image_filename` as option of `sg.Button`, or you will get `AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'image_filename'`.